# How to set code-behind path after moving an .aspx file to a new folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have an `Employee.aspx` page. First it was in a folder named `Master`. Now I moved it to `Employee` folder.

When I run the project it shows me the old path (Master/Employee.aspx) path and throws an error

> The resource cannot be found( /Master/Employee.aspx).

How can I fix this issue?. If edit the path to use `Employee` it runs

```
http://localhost:49874/Master/Employee.aspx
```

My old path it not showing `Employee` in place of `Master`

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Home.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="~/Employee/Employee.aspx.cs" Inherits="Manjilas.WebForm119" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physically moving ASPX/ASCX files is not enough for them to work again. You need to also update the corresponding file's [page/control directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You have to change the `CodeBehind` value of the `@Page` directive to reflect the new path.

Your ASPX page probably has something like this:

```
<%@Page CodeBehind="~/Master/Employee.aspx.cs" ... %>
```

It should become

```
<%@Page CodeBehind="~/Employee/Employee.aspx.cs" ... %>
```

Also, the URL you use to access the page will also change from:

```
http://localhost:49874/Master/Employee.aspx
```

to

```
http://localhost:49874/Employee/Employee.aspx
```

---

A side note:  It is possible for odd compilation errors to persist after changing the .Net version if the Temporary ASP.NET files did not get refreshed. You can fix this by manually emptying the directory:

```
%WINDIR%\Mircosoft.NET\Framework\${version}\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
```

change the `${version}` to your current .NET framework version that IIS uses. (If you use .NET 3.5 or 3.0, then the `${version}` should be 2.0...)

Comment: Is there an `Employee.aspx.cs` file in the same folder where the .aspx is moved to? I mean, you moved both the `Employee.aspx` and the `Employee.aspx.cs` together, right?

Comment: ya is there I have added

Comment: Can you post the code of the aspx file ( I need the page directive) and the definition of the code behind (the namespace and class name part) ? Also, did you recompile the project?

Comment: Nothing is there in that form just namespace Manjilas
{
    public partial class WebForm119 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

Comment: @`Ivaylo Slavov, Ya I did but no change ..Same error

Comment: Your url should be `http://localhost:49874/Employee/Employee.aspx`, not `http://localhost:49874/Master/Employee.aspx`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I do not understand. Did you fix the problem? Which url works and which does not? I am getting confused...

Comment: http://localhost:49874/Master/Employee.aspx works...in this same url if I edit master into Employee then it works. When I run the program http://localhost:49874/Master/Employee.aspx showing as url

Comment: @BrunoBlane, did you configure a starting page for your project? Does the correct url `http://localhost:49874/Employee/Employee.aspx` work? What do you expect to happen if you hit the non-existing url (`http://localhost:49874/Master/Employee.aspx`)?